# Ordered basis proof

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, ordered-fields

If e1,e2, e3 and f1 f2 f3 are ordered basis of R^3 I was able to prove that

T(x1e1 + x2e2 + x3e3) = x3f1 + x1f2 + x2f3,

Is a linear map. But what if I added x1 x2 x3

S(x1e1 + x2e2 + x3e3) = x2x3f1 + x1x3f2 + x1x2f3.

Would this also be a linear map, and if so how would I prove it

Answer (score 0):

Extended hint from what I already gave in the comments:

A few things written in the format of $x_1\cdot e_1+ x_2\cdot e_2+x_3\cdot e_3$

$x_1\cdot e_1+ x_2\cdot e_2+x_3\cdot e_3$

$1~\cdot e_1~+0\cdot ~e_2~+0\cdot e_3=e_1$

$0~\cdot e_1~+1\cdot ~e_2~+0\cdot e_3=e_2$

$1~\cdot e_1~+1\cdot ~e_2~+0\cdot e_3=e_1+e_2$

So then, we ask the question, what is $S(e_1)$?  What is $S(e_2)$?  What is $S(e_1)+S(e_2)$?  What is $S(e_1+e_2)$?

> $S(e_1)=S(1\cdot e_1+0\cdot e_2+0\cdot e_3)=0\cdot 0\cdot f_1+1\cdot 0\cdot f_2+1\cdot 0\cdot f_3=0+0+0=0$

Comment: Hi there so sorry I don't really understand. Is there a formating error as well?

Comment: @Elena There shouldn't be any formatting errors.  I am merely pointing out that if I want to write $e_1$ in the form $x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3$ then I use $x_1=1, x_2=0,$ and $x_3=0$.  This allows me to calculate $S(e_1)$.  Similarly you can calculate the others.  If it so happened that $S$ *was* linear then you should be able to say something about the relationship between $S(e_1+e_2)$ and $S(e_1)+S(e_2)$